# matlab: how to delete an element from a row vector

Tags: matlab

I have written a function myMerge which merges two sorted row vectors, this works as it should.

I am now trying to write a new function MergedExp which calls myMerge and then checks to see if any of the elements are the same and if so removes one. for example if I input the two row vectors [1,3,5,6] and [2,5,7,8] myMerge would give [1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8] and i want MergedExp to produce [1,2,3,5,6,7,8]
 This is what I have so far

```
function [ answer ] = MergedExp( a,b )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

Merge=myMerge(a,b);
l=length(a)+length(b);

for i=1:l-1
    if (Merge(i)==Merge(i+1))
       Merge(i)=[];
    end
end
end
```

When i remove the semi colons in order to see each step of the function working it does give the answer i'm after but still shows an error message.

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a specific assignment, precluding the use of ready-made functions like `union`? If so, consider the effect of shortening the vector inside the loop given that `for` uses a fixed set of indices. Hint 1: a `while` loop evaluates its condition every iteration. Hint 2: alternatively, consider the result of `Merge(2:end)~=Merge(1:end-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using MATLAB's inbuilt function `unique`.

For instance,

```
MergedList = [1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5]
MergedList = unique(MergedList)
```

Output:

```
MergedList =

     1     2     3     4     5
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry I should have mentioned that i'm attempting this without inbuilt functions if possible

Comment: @user3058633, I'll come back to this if it hasn't been answered in a few minutes. But, for now, see if this helps: The size of your array is changing as you go through the loop. So, your for loop limits cannot be the same anymore. Plus, there is a slight error in your duplicate finding algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have comes from the fact that you loop through the nearly whole vector, `1` to `length(vector)-1`, but while doing so, you remove some elements. Therefore at some point, the `for` loop reaches an index that do not correspond to a vector element anymore. And this causes an error.

One of the many solutions to this is store the indexes to remove, and remove them once the `for` loop is done.

```
ind_to_remove = [];
for i=1:l-1
  if (Merge(i)==Merge(i+1))
    ind_to_remove = [ind_to_remove i];
  end
end
Merge(ind_to_remove) = [];
```